# Apache Spark 2.x shuffle parquet on reading

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

Code:

```
System.out.println(storageFrame.toJavaRDD().partitions().size());
String path = getDataPathForSave();
storageFrame.show(); // Dataset<Row>
storageFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path);
sparkSession.read().parquet(path).show();
```

StdOut:

```
2
+---------------+---------+---------------+
|index1234567890|p6e616d65|p20636974794964|
+---------------+---------+---------------+
|              0|   Андрей|              1|
|              1|   Леонид|              2|
|              2|   Сергей|              1|
|              3| Григорий|              4|
+---------------+---------+---------------+

+---------------+---------+---------------+
|index1234567890|p6e616d65|p20636974794964|
+---------------+---------+---------------+
|              2|   Сергей|              1|
|              3| Григорий|              4|
|              0|   Андрей|              1|
|              1|   Леонид|              2|
+---------------+---------+---------------+
```

Why strings are shuffled and how I can avoid this? For `storageFrame.orderBy("index1234567890").write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(path);` result are same.

I use **spark-sql_2.11** version **2.1.0**.

You can [download dataframe from my dropbox (4kb).](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzcqaodqw7mr7im/df.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Deleted incorrect answer and found this:

http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Sorting-within-partitions-is-not-maintained-in-parquet-td18618.html

> This is an optimization to avoid overloading the scheduler with many small tasks.  It bin-packs data into tasks based on the file size.
>
> You can disable it by setting `spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes` very high (higher than `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`).

Comment: This is strange, because in Apache Spark 1.6 this behavior was not.

Comment: I've misunderstood then, unless you were using a similar toy dataset and it was a coincidence that the result was correctly sorted across partitions?

Comment: You are absolutely right and I'm wrong. Did some more digging and found something, will update answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to my problem. Unfortunately, this advice did not help me. I have tried: `SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("My Spark App").config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", 134217728/2).config("spark.sql.files.openCostInBytes", 134217728*4).master("local[*]").getOrCreate()`